# MVC Calling Action Method Twice on FileContentResult in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to return a PDF byte array to the client browser inline so it displays right in Internet Explorer.

When this code is ran:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> DisplayPDF()
{
    var testImageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("This is filled in with a base 64 string that is a image");
    var pdf = _IPDF.Render(testImageBytes);
    return new FileContentResult(pdf, "application/pdf");
}
```

It calls the action method twice, essentially going through all the logic 2 separate times in IE even though both responses are a 200. In Chrome it does not do this, and if I download the file instead of displaying inline it also does not do this in IE or Chrome.

Is there any way to prevent this as pulling the images multiple times is obviously not very efficient in a real world scenario.